# Look for key in jsonb array, LIKE with @>

Tags: postgresql

How can I use `@>` to look into a `jsonb` array, to find data like `'%Par%'`  or `'%ar%'`?  The data in the table looks like

```
[
  {"city":"Paris","country":"FRA"},
  {"city":"Parana","country"‌​:"ARG"}
]
```

I prefer a solution with `@>` because I'm using sequelize, and the ORM have no full syntax conversion to/from `jsonb`.

I was trying something like that , but give error:

```
select * from "customer" where   "customer"."location" #>>'[{city}]'  LIKE '%ar%'
```

this give 0 results:

```
select * from "customer" where   "customer"."location" ->>'[city]'  LIKE '%ar%' ;
```

Comment: Why are you using a tool which does not fully support your use case?  Or Why are you using a PostgreSQL feature that is not fully supported by the ORM?

Comment: because ORM solve most of 95% querys in a fast way , mixing graphql and my own erd  definition all automatically, just having problems with some search with jsonb, but I modify the sources from the ORM to solve this. do you have any solution for this case?

Comment: If you are using an obfuscation layer, then you also need to live with the (many) limitations of that obfuscation layer.

Comment: well 25 years i'm living not only with obfuscation... programming and database always was not perfect lol

Comment: Do all items in that JSONB array have the same structure?  If so, why don't you just normalize them into a proper table?  That would work nicely with your ORM, too.

Comment: because i want to use the powerfull of json in postgress, and i like it, works much better for frontend @dezso , do you know programming using redux-form and graphql, i can't go go working with traditional way, the world is changing and postgress give you jsonb